# Determining voxelized .json file format

Tags: voxel

I don't know if this forum is the right place to post this question. If not please point me to the right place.
I come across a `.json` file format that contains voxelized information from [this](https://github.com/BijoySingh/Legolization-Computer-Graphics.git) project on GitHub. The author seems to have abandoned the project. The content of the `.json` file is like

```
{
 "dimension": [ {
  "width": "26",
  "height": "41",
  "depth": "10"
 } ],
 "voxels": [ 
   { "id": "voxel_0", "x": "12", "y": "37", "z": "0" },
   { "id": "voxel_1", "x": "12", "y": "38", "z": "0" },
   { "id": "voxel_2", "x": "13", "y": "38", "z": "0" },
   { "id": "voxel_3", "x": "12", "y": "38", "z": "1" },
   { "id": "voxel_4", "x": "13", "y": "38", "z": "1" },
   { "id": "voxel_5", "x": "14", "y": "38", "z": "1" },
   { "id": "voxel_6", "x": "13", "y": "37", "z": "0" },
   { "id": "voxel_7", "x": "14", "y": "38", "z": "0" },
   { "id": "voxel_8", "x": "14", "y": "37", "z": "0" },
   { "id": "voxel_9", "x": "14", "y": "36", "z": "0" },
   { "id": "voxel_10", "x": "13", "y": "36", "z": "0" },
   { "id": "voxel_11", "x": "12", "y": "36", "z": "0" },
   { "id": "voxel_12", "x": "12", "y": "39", "z": "2" }
 ]
}
```

Does any know what file format this is and what software is used to create it?
Perhaps something that can voxelize an `.obj` file and output to this `.json` format?

I looked at Blender but it does not output this `.json` format.

Comment: Minecraft JSON, perhaps ?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Unfortunately that's not it. Perhaps this is something that author created himself so there is no specification anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Well...looks like I have found the answer myself.
This JSON format is actually not any standardized format or associated with any program. So there is no specification anywhere.  This is a custom format created by the owner (Arjan Westerdiep) of [this site](https://drububu.com/miscellaneous/voxelizer/).